# Receiving OTP SMS Via AT+CMGL Command (e.g. Whatsapp)

Tags: node.js, serial-port, sms, at-command, sms-gateway

I'm new to GSM AT Commands and I'm using ZTE MF190S USB 3G USB Modem with [Modem Nodejs Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modem) also tried with MS Hyperterminal.

The problem I'm facing that when I receive SMS using `AT+CMGL="ALL"` from Whatsapp (as example) I got in sender number field `81084326797126204` which is an invalid phone number and should be "Whatsapp" instead although the manufacture's software is showing message from Whatsapp normally.

Note: I tried to decode it as a Hexadecimal string but not done.

```
> AT+CSCS="GSM"
> AT+CPMS="ME"
> AT+CMGL="ALL"
//Result
+CMGL: 0,"REC UNREAD","81084326797126204",,"20/05/30,14:53:55+08"
        FEFF000000000000000000000000000000000000020
```

As described in this [link](https://www.developershome.com/sms/cmglCommand.asp)

> +CMGL: index,message_status,address,[address_text],[service_center_time_stamp][,address_type,sms_message_body_length]sms_message_body[+CMGL:
>   ...]
>
> The address Field
>
> The third field of the information response of the +CMGL AT command,
>   address, is a string that contains the address/phone number stored in
>   the SMS message header. If the SMS message read is an incoming SMS
>   message, the address field contains the originator address. If the SMS
>   message read is an outgoing SMS message, the address field contains
>   the recipient address. Usually the address field value is a phone
>   number formatted using the typical ISDN / telephony numbering plan
>   (ITU E.164/E.163). For example, "+85291234567".
>
> The address_text Field
>
> The fourth field of the information response of the +CMGL AT command,
>   address_text, is a string that contains the text associated to address
>   in the phonebook. For example, if the text "Alice" is associated to
>   the phone number "91234567" in the phonebook, address_text will be
>   "Alice". The AT command +CSCS (command name in text: Select TE
>   Character Set) can be used to specify the character set for displaying
>   address_text. Note that address_text is an optional field. Some
>   GSM/GPRS modems and mobile phones (examples: most Nokia products,
>   including my Nokia 6021) leave this field empty.

**How can I identify the message is from Whatsapp or any other services providers names?**

Comment: Let me understand. You would just like to have The "WhatsApp" string in the fourth parameter of `AT+CGML`? Is there a reason why you can't just identify those messages by parsing that specific number from every message displayed in the list? Have you tried to insert that number in the phonebook?

Comment: `You would just like to have The "WhatsApp" string in the fourth parameter of AT+CGML?` Yes Exactly, i don't know why it's can't be displayed as well as manufacture's software, i think maybe there is missing command to show more details about SMS, i've tried `AT+CSDH=1` to get SMS header also tried with Text and PDU modes.

Comment: I've tried to write an answer. I'm not 100% sure it will solve your issue, but it could be helpful anyway for someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> The fourth field of the information response of the **+CMGL** AT command, address_text, is a string that contains the text associated to address in the phonebook

If your device used to recognize that number, it probably was in one of device's phonebooks, and maybe it got deleted.

What you can try to do is to store again the number using **`AT+CPBW`** command:

> **AT+CPBW=[<index>][,<number>[,<type>[,<text>]]]**
>
> where
>
> - **index** is the record position in the phonebook. If omitted the record is stored in the first free position
> - **number** is the number to be stored in phonebook, in string format
> - **type** is the number type; 129 for national scheme, 145 for international scheme
> - **text** is the name of the entry in the phonebook

So, in your case:

```
AT+CPBW=,"81084326797126204",129,"WhatsApp"
```

And after it you should see the name appearing in `+CGML` list. You might need a device reboot after the PB write in order to see the change making effect.

The change is done in the *current* phonebook, usually the SIM card. It can be queried with command `AT+CPBS?` (it also allows to change it; see the guide for further explanation).

I suggest exploring the content of every phonebook, in order to discover any device (and SIM) default contents. The command to read phonebook entries is **`AT+CPBR**`. Providing

```
AT+CPBR=1,N
```

all index between 1  and N are shown. If you set N to the size of the phonebook, you can list all the entries in it.